# XmlDocument reading XML Document comment Issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument, xml-comments

I am using XmlDocument to parse xml file, but it seems that XmlDocument is always reading xml comments as a xml nodes:

My C# code

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(filename);

foreach (XmlNode node in xml.FirstChild.ChildNodes) {

}
```

Xml file

```
<project>
    <!-- comments-->
    <application name="app1">
        <property name="ip" value="10.18.98.100"/>
    </application>
</project>
```

Shouldn't .NET skip XML comments?

Comment: a small point: XmlDocument has nothing to do with C#. It's part of .NET, not part of C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but `node.NodeType` schould by `XmlNodeType.Comment`.
If it wouldn't read the comments you also couldn't access them, but you can do something like the following to get all "real nodes":

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(filename);
var realNodes = from n in xml.Descendants("application")
                where n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment
                select n;

foreach(XNode node in realNodes)
{ 
    //your code
}
```

or without LINQ/XDocument:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(filename);

foreach (XmlNode node in xml.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
{
     if(node.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
     {
         //your code
     }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me it should be " where n.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment " ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [XmlNodeType.Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodetype%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(filename);

        foreach (XmlNode node in xml.FirstChild.ChildNodes) 
        {
            if(node.GetType() == XmlNodeType.Comment)
            {
               //Do nothing
            }
            else
            {
               //Your code goes here.
            }
       }
```